# How to animate a progress bar with jquery and percent unit just once?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate my "HTML level" progress bar. when i hover the parent div, i want the progress bar to rich "90%". the best way I found was toset the "width : 90%". but when I hover the parent div twice for exemple, the progress bar animates one more time. i've tried to use "px" unit, and it worked, but it's not responsive and we never get the same result if we zoom. How can I fix this please ?

PS: i want my code to work the same as in "snippet" down here, but when i hover it again and again in my browser, it animates many times

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#langages").on('mouseenter', function () { 
        $("#fr").animate({ width: "90%" });
    });
});
```

```css
#langages{
  height: 100px;
}

#fr {
  width: 20%;
}

.size {
  max-height: 25em;
}

.bgBlue{
    background-color: #5DD5FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="langages" class="bg-white col-10 text-center mx-                   auto mb-5 fs-5 shadow rounded size">
  <div class="col-11 mx-auto my-4 text-start">
    Français
    <div class="progress mt-1">
      <div class="progress-bar bgBlue" id="fr" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="sr-only">90% Complete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, did you saw my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class when animation is done, and check if element got the class when mouseenter event. Like this, animation run only once.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#langages").on('mouseenter', function () { 
      // we check if animation was done once
      if (!$("#fr").hasClass('animationDone')) {
        // if not, then we do animation
        $("#fr").animate({
          width: "90%"
        }, 500, function() {
          // we add class animationDone once 
          $("#fr").addClass('animationDone');
          console.log('Animate once');
        });
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#langages{
  height: 100px;
}

#fr {
  width: 20%;
}

.size {
  max-height: 25em;
}

.bgBlue{
    background-color: #5DD5FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="langages" class="bg-white col-10 text-center mx-                   auto mb-5 fs-5 shadow rounded size">
  <div class="col-11 mx-auto my-4 text-start">
    Français
    <div class="progress mt-1">
      <div class="progress-bar bgBlue" id="fr" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="sr-only">90% Complete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much The_Death_Raw !! it works. I have just another question, how can I disable It on small devices?

Comment: Your welcome, you can upvote my answer if you want to ;)
You can check width viewport with var windowWidth = window.innerWidth; and add condition like : if (windowWidth > 500) { }

Answer (score 0):

on of the best way for responsive is use of **vw**. of course you can defined variable, get screen.width and do some Math operation.

```
  $("#fr").animate({ width: "90vw" });

  $(document).ready(function () {
    let userScreenWidth =String(screen.width);
    userScreenWidth = userScreenWidth.substring(0, 2) * 90;
    // console.log(userScreenWidth.substring(0, 2) * 90);
  $("#langages").on('mouseenter', function () { 
      $("#fr").animate({ width:userScreenWidth+'px' });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you  Mohammad, but it still not working as I want. i tried your code, but every time I over the parent div, the progress bar animates and I only want to animate once. maybe there is another way to animate the progress bar when you scroll to this part ?